# Pytest Stops Running After First Failure

Tags: pytest

I am running tests on two lists using Pytest

```
  import pytest
  def test_TestsRunAfterFailure():
     x = [1,2,3,4]
     test = [4, 5, 6]
     for t in test:
         assert (t in x)
```

I want the test to measure each variable even after the first failure so I know which variables are failing. The output generated suggests that it is stopping after the first failure.

```
      E           assert 5 in [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I have googled the issue and the suggestion is to run pytest with the following argument

```
     pytest --maxfail=3
```

However the result suggests that it is stopping after the first assert is false. Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test is a function, and the problem is that your code, as written, only has a single test (`test_TestsRunAfterFailure`). When the code hits the first failing `assert` statement, that test has failed.

If you want to run multiple tests, you need to either:

- Write multiple test functions, or
- [Parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html) the test

The second solution is probably what you want, and might look something like this:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('value', [4, 5, 6])
def test_TestsRunAfterFailure(value):
   x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
   assert (value in x)
```

Running the above code will produce output like:

```
===================================== test session starts =====================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.4, pytest-6.0.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
plugins: cov-2.11.1, flake8-1.0.7, asyncio-0.14.0, xonsh-0.9.26
collected 3 items

test_values.py .FF                                                                      [100%]

========================================== FAILURES ===========================================
________________________________ test_TestsRunAfterFailure[5] _________________________________

value = 5

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('value', [4, 5, 6])
    def test_TestsRunAfterFailure(value):
       x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>      assert (value in x)
E      assert 5 in [1, 2, 3, 4]

test_values.py:6: AssertionError
________________________________ test_TestsRunAfterFailure[6] _________________________________

value = 6

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('value', [4, 5, 6])
    def test_TestsRunAfterFailure(value):
       x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>      assert (value in x)
E      assert 6 in [1, 2, 3, 4]

test_values.py:6: AssertionError
=================================== short test summary info ===================================
FAILED test_values.py::test_TestsRunAfterFailure[5] - assert 5 in [1, 2, 3, 4]
FAILED test_values.py::test_TestsRunAfterFailure[6] - assert 6 in [1, 2, 3, 4]
================================= 2 failed, 1 passed in 0.15s =================================
```